# How to add existing user to an existing group in centos 7?

Tags: centos, rhel, users, group

I'm trying to add an existing user called Jim, to the current group called hoho, that I've created. I've looked up the command, and this is all I got.

> **useradd -g hoho Jim**

Then when I checked to see if it's in the group, like this:

> **ls -l**

It came up with Jim still not in the group **hoho**. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to give him this group id, while I moved him to a new group.

Comment: use this command  `usermod -a -G hoho jim` and to check if user is member of group use `id jim`

Comment: Are you trying to change the folders group, or the actual users group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `ls -l` will give you any information on user `Jim`, as it will yield file system info only. Try

```
groups Jim
```

instead.